# Array.splice duplicate edit and insert after , unexpected result

Tags: javascript

In the following example (https://jsfiddle.net/dhkzwxr1/2/) : 
I try to understand the behaviour of splice

```
const arr = [];
arr[0] = {name:"Jani",age:24};
arr[1] = {name:"Hege",age:32};
arr[2] = {name:"Stale",age:52};
arr[3] = {name:"Kai Jim",age:42};
arr[4] = {name:"Borge",age:25};

arr.splice(1, 0, {name:"Lene",age:27});
console.log(arr);
```

Insert at

Behave as expected

```
const arr2 = [];
arr2[0] = {name:"Jani",age:24};
arr2[1] = {name:"Hege",age:32};
arr2[2] = {name:"Stale",age:52};
arr2[3] = {name:"Kai Jim",age:42};
arr2[4] = {name:"Borge",age:25};

const jani = arr2[0];

jani.age = 19

arr2.splice(1, 0, jani);
console.log(arr2);
```

Output :

```
Array(6)
0: {name: "Jani", age: 19}
1: {name: "Jani", age: 19}
2: {name: "Hege", age: 32}
3: {name: "Stale", age: 52}
4: {name: "Kai Jim", age: 42}
5: {name: "Borge", age: 25}
length: 6
```

Why `arr2[0].age === 19` and not 24  ?

Comment: Because you're inserting the same element into the array.  The object referenced by `jani` is in the array twice once you splice it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like said commentator above Because you're inserting the same element into the array. The object referenced by jani is in the array twice once you splice it in.

and you should create a new object, you can do it by method `Object.assign()`
easy fix
`var jani = Object.assign({}, arr2[0]);`

working example

https://jsfiddle.net/fdtgvcLw/

When you assign one variable to another, it's not that both those variables are now linked by reference; you're misunderstanding what "pass by reference" means here.

A variable holding an object does not "directly" hold an object. What it holds is a reference to an object. When you assign that reference from one variable to another, you're making a copy of that reference. Now both variables hold a reference to an object. Modifying the object through that reference changes it for both variables holding a reference to that object.

When you assign a new value to one of the variables, you're just modifying the value that variable holds. The variable now ceases to hold a reference to the object, and instead holds something else. The other variable still holds its reference to the original object, the assignment didn't influence it at all.

Let's visualize:

```
var objOne = {
  x: 1,
  y: 2
};

// objOne -> { x: 1, y: 2 }

var objTwo = objOne;

// objOne -> { x: 1, y: 2 } <- objTwo

objTwo.x = 2;

// objOne -> { x: 2, y: 2 } <- objTwo (update object via objTwo variable)

objTwo = {};

// objOne -> { x: 2, y: 2 }, objTwo -> {}
```

This is how pass-by-reference works. Here objTwo is referring to objOne so whatever you do with objTwo will also happen with objOne.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an issue with `slice`. What happens is that objects in JavaScript, like all other non-primitive values, are passed by reference.

So even if you insert an object into array, and update it after that, the variable will have the updated value. I think the most important thing to understand is that `jani` variable in your case does not have an actual value of the object, but just a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not about splice. its with you have assigning object, and changing it's value to 19.
Then you insert another record to the array.

If you comment the `var jani = arr2[0];` and splice it like you have done it before.

It would work.